# Pop-Up que aparezca despues de un tiempo en la página

Tags: javascript

Tengo una duda con JavaScript (soy completamente nuevo con este lenguaje), quiero diseñar un pop-up pero viendo guías lo máximo a lo que he llegado es a esto:

```
var btnAbrirPopup = document.getElementById('btn-abrir-popup'),
    overlay = document.getElementById('overlay'),
    popup = document.getElementById('popup'),
    btnCerrarPopup = document.getElementById('btn-cerrar-popup');

btnAbrirPopup.addEventListener('click', function(){
    overlay.classList.add('active');
    popup.classList.add('active');
});


btnCerrarPopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
    overlay.classList.remove('active');   
    popup.classList.remove('active'); 
});
```

Básicamente lo que hace este código es al hacer click en un botón aparece el pop-up y al hacer click en la "x" que aparece en el pop-up cerrarlo.

Lo que quiero es establecer que por ejemplo a los 3s de haber entrado en la página aparezca el pop-up de forma automática. He estado probando con setTimeOut() pero no se como integrarlo en ese código.

Gracias.

Comment: Si quieres que se ejecute una función tras X tiempo de haberse cargado la página, debes llamarla en el script JS de la página con la función setTimeOut(), por ejemplo, para mostrar una alerta al cabo de un minuto en la página `setTimeout(() => {alert('Hola')}, 6000)`. Eso quiere decir que en tu código necesitas una función que abra el popup en ese tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes  utilizar el setTimeout de JS para ello:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    TuFuncion()
}, 3000);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp